# Fit of individual children in Stack

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `Stack` widget with some children. One of those children is an `Align` which has a `Container` child which has a `Column` child. This `Column` has some children. Now, in my `Stack`, the `Column` is way bigger than it should be (it fills the complete screen) although a third of that space would be enough. I'd like to know how I can use something like `Flexible` so I can use the `fit` property to tighten up the space. Is this possible?
Here is a representation of my code:

```
new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Container(...),
    new Align( // This takes up way more space than needed!
      alignment: new Alignment(1.0, 1.0) // This widget should be displayed at the bottom
      child: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget> [
            new Container(child: new Center(child: new Text("text"))),
            new Row(children: [...]),
            new Row(children: [...]),
            new Row(children: [...]),
            new Row(children: [...]),
          ]
        )
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

I tried playing around with the `fit` property but without any luck.

Comment: edited my answer (and removed my comments as I was wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `Column` has `mainAxisSize` defaulting to `MainAxisSize.max`.
Which means that `Column` will take all the available height.

In your case, you don't want that. So you can set that value to `MainAxisSize.min`, which will do the opposite : fit it's children.

The end result is :

```
    child: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(...),
        new Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[new Text("foo"), new Text("hello world")],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: That did not work. It is still taking up all of the screen. I could set the `top` property but that'd mean that I hard code the size. It should take up just as much as it needs on every screen.

Comment: I added some extra code and was actually wrong about the child of the `Align`. Could you take another look?

Comment: The only thing that that `Container` does is set the background color. I do not see how that could be the problem. I'm pretty sure that your example would have the same issue as what I have now, but you can not see the actual size because your `Column` does not have a background color.

Comment: But the `Container` does have a child, the `Column`.

Comment: That one actually does also have a child but I do not see how that one would have an effect on the behavior  of the second child of my `Stack`